# Getting duplicate id error in xhtml pages after upgrading ICEfaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

I am getting duplicate id error in my xhtml pages after adding the below context param in web.xml

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

below is the error message

```
org.icefaces.impl.application.ExtendedExceptionHandler handle
WARNING: queued exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: component with duplicate id "v9g4o62-retrieve-update" found
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIds(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletU
tils.java:100)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIds(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletU
tils.java:116)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIds(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletU
tils.java:116)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIds(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletU
tils.java:82)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.DefaultFaceletsStateManagementStrategy.saveView(DefaultFaceletsStateMan
agementStrategy.java:536)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:188)
        at javax.faces.application.StateManager.getViewState(StateManager.java:253)
        at org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMResponseWriter$WriteViewStateMarkup.write(DOMResponseWriter.java:614)
        at org.icefaces.impl.util.DOMUtils.printNode(DOMUtils.java:373)
        at org.icefaces.impl.util.DOMUtils.printNode(DOMUtils.java:355)
        at org.icefaces.impl.util.DOMUtils.printNode(DOMUtils.java:355)
        at org.icefaces.impl.util.DOMUtils.printNode(DOMUtils.java:355)
        at org.icefaces.impl.util.DOMUtils.printNode(DOMUtils.java:306)
        at org.icefaces.impl.util.DOMUtils.printNode(DOMUtils.java:290)
        at org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMResponseWriter.endDocument(DOMResponseWriter.java:238)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguag
e.java:1983)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:116)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
        at com.mtcom.abc.webapp.servlet.abcServlet.service(abcServlet.java:104)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:270)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java
:3436)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:340
2)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderIm
pl.java:255)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

<11 Jul, 2016 3:49:16 PM IST> <Warning> <org.icefaces.impl.application.ExtendedExceptionHandler> <BEA-000000> <queu
ed exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: component with duplicate id "v9g4o62-retrieve-update" found
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIds(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletU
tils.java:100)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIds(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletU
tils.java:116)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIds(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletU
tils.java:116)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIds(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletU
tils.java:82)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.DefaultFaceletsStateManagementStrategy.saveView(DefaultFaceletsStateMan
agementStrategy.java:536)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

I have upgraded the following technologies in my project

Icefaces 1.8 to 3.3

jsf 1.X to 2.0

Not able to find what is the exact root cause . Pleae do needful

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you show us the offending xhtml page code ?

Comment: @Raj ViewExpiredException can be resolved by changing the scope of the backing bean

Comment: hmm what is the role of the bean ? does the user have to login to access it ?

Comment: I don't exactly know what your beans do but I suggest those 2 beans with view scope to have session scope, anyway I doubt even when you get rid of `ViewExpirationException` you'll still get `Duplicate id` error above